# How to test state in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

So I have a simple counter app,

```
class CounterApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CounterAppState createState() => _CounterAppState();
}

class _CounterAppState extends State<CounterApp> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Text(_counter.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So how do I test the `_counter` state?

I tried doing this,

```
testWidgets("counter", (tester) async {
  const key = Key("counter");
  await tester.pumpWidget(const CounterApp(key: key));

  final state = tester.state(find.byKey(key));

  expect(state._counter, 0);
});
```

But I get error `Error: The getter '_counter' isn't defined for the class`. Are we even supposed to test state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to specify the type while using `state` method to avoid compiling errors:

```dart
final _CounterAppState state = tester.state(find.byKey(key));
```

Second, `_CounterAppState` and `_counter` are private and you shouldn't test private classes/variables directly. You can make the class public and provide a public getter for the private variable:

```dart
int get testCounter => _counter;
```

However, this is a way to access private declarations which I wouldn't recommend. Instead, I would recommend annotating your public variable/class with `@visibleForTesting` to make dart analyzer warn you if annotated code is not used in a private way. Don't forget to import foundation or meta library.

#### [visibleForTesting top-level constant](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/visibleForTesting-constant.html)

> Used to annotate a declaration that was made public, so that it is
> more visible than otherwise necessary, to make code testable.
>
> Tools, such as the analyzer, can provide feedback if
>
> - the annotation is associated with a declaration not in the lib folder of a package, or a private declaration, or a declaration in an
>   unnamed static extension, or
> - the declaration is referenced outside of its defining library or a library which is in the test folder of the defining package.

Here is the implementation:

```dart
// Import the foundation library
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CounterApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterAppState createState() => CounterAppState();
}

// Add the annotation above the class
@visibleForTesting
class CounterAppState extends State<CounterApp> {
  // Add the annotation above the variable
  @visibleForTesting
  int counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Text(counter.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You might want to remove the annotation after testing.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `@visibleForTesting` annotation, many answers lack this addition.